# Java: make the Method continue after Exception

Tags: java, exception

I have some code that reads from an Excel file, uses the addValue Method from our logic Layer after every row to add data to Database.

Now I have a loop which goes through the rows and one that goes through the cells.
After reading a Table Row from Excel it executes the addValue Method, which itself throws an Exception if something is not right.

What the Program does now is that it stops when the first Exception appears, so for example if the corrupted Data is in the middle of that Excel file, it imports everything until reaching that corrupted Data and stops.

How can I make it continue after catching the Exception that addValue throws?

```
      try {
                    // abfangen des ersten durchlaufes 
                    if (id == -1) {
                    } else {
                        /*
                         * java.lang.System.out.println(name);
                         * java.lang.System.out.println(id);
                         * java.lang.System.out.println(value);
                         * java.lang.System.out.println(comment);
                         */
                        java.lang.System.out.println("value"+ value);
                        sysInterface.addValue(ident, name, value, comment);

                        workbook.close();
                    }

                } catch (LogicException | IOException e) {
                    
                    
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Adding Value unsuccessful!");

                    alert.setContentText(e.getMessage()
                            + " Import aborted. \nClassificationNumber " 
      +name+ " has to be in Database before importing.");

                    alert.showAndWait();
                    return;

                }
            }
```

This block is within a loop which runs as many times as the Excel Table has rows.

Comment: what do you think `return;` line is doing?

Comment: If you get an IOException, you should not try to continue reading.  If the file can’t be read, what makes you think the second try will be able to read it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that you also have the "***finally***" case, where, *after* the call is made and the error is *caught*, you can reiterate from where you left off.

### Short example:

```
public foo bar(){
    try{
        // try here
    } catch(Exception here){ 
        //handle here
    }
    finally{ 
        /*
        * you can return to your loop after the exception has been caught, from 
        * here by calling it again, recursively */
    }
}
```

Comment: i first tought of something similar aswell, but it seemed like thinking a bit to far away. The "continue" keyword did it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: As another user suggested earlier, "continue" might cause problems with your IDE. If the answer helped you, I invite you to approve it.

Answer (score 0):

If the block is in a loop, then I assume what you really want is to say something like "try this, but catch any exceptions then skip the offending record and continue the loop".

If that's the case, simply change your "return" statement to "continue". the Continue keyword says "skip the rest of execution in this step of the loop and go to the next step.

Comment: Suggestion `continue` here is imprudent. `continue` breaks the "flow" through the method and effectively disables automated refactorings of the IDE. In 15+ year of coding Java I never needed to use `continue`. By what the OP showed the better solution is to simply remove the `return` statement.

Comment: That´s it! Thank you :)